# Interface from C-Programm in XCode to SWI-Prolog

Tags: c, xcode, macos, swi-prolog

i want to interface from c-code using XCode IDE under MAC OS X to SWI-Prolog.

I´ve included the header files and use the following sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SWI-Prolog.h>
#include <SWI-Stream.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

char *av[10];
int ac = 0;

av[ac++] = "/opt/local/lib/swipl-6.2.2/bin/i386-darwin12.2.1/swipl";
av[ac++] = "-x";
av[ac++] = "mystate";
av[ac]   = NULL;

#ifdef READLINE /* Remove if you don't want readline */
PL_initialise_hook(install_readline);
#endif

if ( !PL_initialise(ac, av) )
    PL_halt(1);

PL_halt(PL_toplevel() ? 0 : 1);


printf("done...\n");
return 0;
}
```

I also linked at the build settings to the header and lib paths:

Header Search Path: /opt/local/lib/swipl-6.2.2/include

Library Search Path: /opt/local/lib/swipl-6.2.2/lib/i386-darwin12.2.1

But while running the code i get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PL_halt", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_PL_initialise", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_PL_toplevel", referenced from:
       _main in main.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone can help me to get my code running?

Thanks in Advance and Kind regards

Solick

Comment: mismatch i386 vs x86_64?

Comment: hmm this was the installation files for MAC OS X... but maybe i should try to compile swi-prolog myself on my mac... thanks for the hint, i´ll give it a try...
But on the other hand: Running swi-prolog from terminal works fine and without problems...

Comment: ld warnings on architecture x86_64... seems misconfigured

Comment: hmm that could be the problem... i use the precompiled version from the website for MAC and running swi from console works fine. Maybe the libs are only compiled for 32 Bit on MAC?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set the correct paths in the settings, it doesn't automatically find the correct library to link with. You have to add the actual library as well.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But which lib and where to link? There are a lot of *.dylib files in the lib directory...

Answer (score 0):

I work in Ubuntu (and yes, in Windows, still), and I've come to appreciate the [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config) support.

If you are already comfortable with it, note that when compiled locally, SWI-Prolog generates a directory ~/lib/pkgconfig.

Then you could add that directory to pkg-config configuration, and use the SW with (IMHO) a good support.

Comment: Hi, no i use the pre-compiled version. The problem is with XCode that the makefile is different (and graphical :)