# Prolog or more recent AI Logic language for Xcode

Tags: xcode, prolog, artificial-intelligence

Does anybody know a library (preferably not SWI-prolog) for using Prolog in Xcode? If not, do you know a library for a more recent language that does a similar job?

Thanks

Comment: Xcode is an IDE. If you mean, use Prolog from Objective-C, there isn't anything specific for it, you'll have to use an implementation with a friendly C binding (like SWI).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using GNU Prolog (gprolog) a lot lately and it has a beautifully simple interface to C which allows you to produce custom executables made of standard code plus your own.

Being a Cocoa programmer too I am not sure how you would integrate the code but section ["10.6  Calling Prolog from C"](http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/manual/gprolog.html#sec334) might give you some ideas on hoe to use it as part of an Xcode application.

The next section, [10.7  Defining a new C main() function](http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/manual/gprolog.html#sec375) might help on how you could translate that code (shown here for clarity) into something more ObjC like:

```
static int
Main_Wrapper(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int nb_user_directive;
  PlBool top_level;

  nb_user_directive = Pl_Start_Prolog(argc, argv);

  top_level = Pl_Try_Execute_Top_Level();

  Pl_Stop_Prolog();

  if (top_level || nb_user_directive)
    return 0;

  fprintf(stderr,
          "Warning: no initial goal executed\n"
          "   use a directive :- initialization(Goal)\n"
          "   or remove the link option --no-top-level"
          " (or --min-bips or --min-size)\n");

  return 1;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return Main_Wrapper(argc, argv);
}
```

Kludging all that into `NSApplicationMain` is going to be fun and interesting!

The only other way I could think of doing it is to make the above code start your Cocoa application maybe by using `objc_msgSend` as described in this answer, ["Calling Cocoa APIs from C"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901508/calling-cocoa-apis-from-c).

Best of luck with it.
Sean.

Comment: Just found this SO question too, related and might also help...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583039/interface-from-c-programm-in-xcode-to-swi-prolog